# C++ template print object name

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class T>
class mytemp {
    public:
    mytemp ();
    print_name()
    {
     cout << "Name is: " << //?
    }
};

mytemp<int> myobject ();
myobject.print_name()
```

I want print_name() function to print this class's name, in this example, print `Name is: myobject`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Objects don't have names, variables do.  And not all objects correspond to variables.  Either way, this isn't possible without passing the name in as an argument.

Comment: This appears to be an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the end goal?

Comment: You can use RTTI, by including #include <typeinfo> and use typeid(*this).name()

Comment: @JensMunk that would give you `mytemp` not `myobject`.

Comment: I think you'd have to use macros of some sort to accomplish this.

Comment: And what do you expect `mytemp<int>().print_name();` to do?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add a member variable that held the objects name.

I'm going to assume that you'd want to make that a `const` member variable. If so you'd do something like this:

```
#define CREATE_MYTEMP(x) mytemp<void> (x){#x}

template <class T>
class mytemp {
    private:
    string _name;
    public:
    mytemp(){}
    mytemp(string name) : _name(name){}
    void print_name() const
    {
        cout << "Name is: " << _name << endl;
    }
};
```

To use this you'd have to pass in a name on construction of the object or use `CREATE_MYTEMP`:

```
mytemp<void> foo("foo");
CREATE_MYTEMP(bar);

foo.print_name(); //prints: "Name is: foo"
bar.print_name(); //prints: "Name is: bar"
```

If you use the default ctor you'll have an empty name:

```
mytemp<void> empty;
empty.print_name(); //prints: "Name is:"
```